# How to get children of two or more nodes in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am looking for an efficient way where I can get all nodes and their children and store them in two different `arraylists` using single `valueEventListener`.

here is my firebase.
[image]

Here is what I have done.

```
 ValueEventListener allCodesListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // This method is called once with the initial value and again
                // whenever data at this location is updated.
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    CouponObj post = postSnapshot.getValue(CouponObj.class);
                    list.add(new CouponObj(post.getCode(), post.getDetail(), post.getExpirationDate(), post.getLikes(), post.getStatus(), post.getSuccessRate(), post.getUsers_today()));
                    Log.e("Get Data", post.getCode());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
    myRef.child("allcodes").addValueEventListener(allCodesListener);
```

In this `listener` I get only children of `allcodes`. Now i can repeat same above code and make another listener and get all children of `more_apps` but I want to know if there's any better way.

**In this scenario**, i have multiple nodes on `firebase`, i want to get them all in `arraylist` and store them in `sqlLite`, i have to write many listeners for that. The problem is that there are more than two nodes and their children. I want to get them all in one go, inside single `listener`.

Comment: on the same onDataChange method you can make another reference to your other child and iterate inside it to add the values into the other arraylist

Comment: There is nothing wrong in nested listeners.

Comment: ok, thank you. For now, I am using multiple listeners to get data.